# Oracle: epoch milleseconds to date/time with time zone included

Tags: oracle, date, time, epoch, zone

I'm a PL/SQL newbie who needs to convert milleseconds since unix epoch to 
a date/time. I can convert to GMT date/time but don't know how to adjust
for the time zone. I'm close but not quite there.

My input is r_msg.OriginationTime, which has a value like 1382552100277

This

```
MpD NUMBER        := (1/24/60/60/1000);        -- Milleseconds per Day

DFmt24 VARCHAR2(21) := 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';    -- Date format

TMPorig24        VARCHAR2(20);

. . .

TMPorig24 := TO_CHAR( DATE '1970-01-01' + MpD * r_msg.OriginationTime, DFmt24);
```

gives something like

```
10/23/2013 18:15:00
```

which is just what I want except it's GMT.

This

```
    TimeZoneOffset VARCHAR(7);

    . . . 

    TimeZoneOffset := tz_offset('America/New_York' );
```

gives

```
-04:00
```

So I just need to do something like

```
TMPorig24 := TMPorig24 + TimeZoneOffset;
```

but I get

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

I've tried several variations but nothing works.

Any help appreciated.

---

Thanks but I'm having problems with the two solutions.

The first solution prints the same time regardless of the time zone.
For example, these print the same values.

TMPorig :=  TO_CHAR(
            FROM_TZ( CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * r_msg.OriginationTime AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

TMPorig2 :=  TO_CHAR(
            FROM_TZ( CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * r_msg.OriginationTime AS TIMESTAMP), 'Pacific/Pago_Pago'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

The second solution

TMPorig := TO_CHAR(
      DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * r_msg.OriginationTime + INTERVAL '-04:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

gives

```
PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal
```

Moveover, '04:00' will be wrong when Daylight Savings Time ends. 
I need an expression for the time difference between EST/EDT and GMT.

*************** WORKS PERFECT THANKS ****************************

TMPorig2 := TO_CHAR (
    FROM_TZ ( CAST (DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * r_msg.OriginationTime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
      AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

---

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer - check the new solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Ok, try this solution instead:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR (
    FROM_TZ (
      CAST (DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * 1382552100277 AS TIMESTAMP),
      'UTC')
    AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') val
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
VAL               
-------------------
10/23/2013 14:15:00
```

---

You have to cast the `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` and use the `FROM_TZ` function to convert the `TIMESTAMP` into `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` datatype. The timezone parameter can be in either format: `America/New_York` or `-04:00`.

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(
    FROM_TZ(
      CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * 1382552100277 AS TIMESTAMP),
      'America/New_York'),
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

That is if you want to have a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` variable. If you want to add the offset from given time zone, then you can use:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(
      DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * 1382552100277 + INTERVAL '-04:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS val
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
VAL               
-------------------
10/23/2013 14:15:00
```

Comment: this is working great for me - do you happen to have some code that goes the other way, from a string to seconds after epoch?

Comment: @dldnh Could you provide a sample data and what output are you expecting?